# Mockito when not working for no parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I have a method in the service class that does a retrofit2 call and I am trying to mock that call.
It works when i try to mock a success call, but does not when i try to mock a 400 response.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ServiceTests{

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceClass serviceClass;

    @Mock
    private Call<...> retrofitCallMock;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    //This is what i've tried
    @Test
    public void succCallTest(){
        //this works
        when(retrofitCallMock.execute()).thenReturn(Response.success(...));
        //run the method in the service class
        assertEquals("success", serviceClass.methodCall());
    }

    @Test
    public void failCallTest(){
        //this doesn't work
        when(retrofitCallMock.execute()).thenReturn(Response.error(400, ...));
        //run the method in the service class
        assertEquals("fail", serviceClass.methodCall());
    }
}
```

The second test would not work as I would get a null object when execute() is called. And thus a nullpointer was thrown afterward.

Any suggestions and recommendations is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your complete test class especially fields, imports and class annotations.

Comment: @mle I have edited the post with more info

Comment: So if `execute` is returning `null` instead of returning `Response.error(400, ...)`, then it sounds like your test _should_ fail.

Comment: And you are not using any runner per annotation on your class? And the `assertEqual` without an `s` comes from which import?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It does fail, but a nullpointer is still thrown. The expected result is for it to return Response.error(400, ...).

Comment: @mle My bad, misspelled it. the assertEquals is from JUnit. The runner should be the Mockito runner. I initialized the mocks before every run.

Comment: Hm so far so good – and can you get us a glimpse into the `serviceClass.methodCall()`?

Comment: @mle There's not much in that method. All it does is try to fetch data from an external api using the retrofit.execute call. And then i just process the response. In this case, response will be null for the second test.

Comment: Ok but where and how dou you get your `retrofitCallMock` aka your real `retrofitCall` in your productive method? Is there may be some kind of `new` creation ongoing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190797/discussion-between-mle-and-dest).

Comment: So what's throwing the NPE?  Maybe you can show the stack trace.

Comment: @mle the retrofitCall is configured to be a bean in a config class. So in the service class it's just autowired.

Comment: Well than everything is fine. No further ideas without seeing the tested method itself.